# How to get ListURL from Create Document Library response?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

When I create document library in SharePoint via Client REST APIs I get different fields to identify library (like Title, EntityTypeName, Id). Sample response when I create library named "Школьные материалы 2.":

```
{
  "d": {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "https://somesite.sharepoint.com/sites/Team_49de5296/_api/Web/Lists(guid'd94587ec-ff65-4b61-b0e8-2a00513494ee')"
       …
    },
    …
    "DocumentTemplateUrl": "/sites/Team_49de5296/2/Forms/template.dotx",
    …
    "EntityTypeName": "2",
    "Id": "d94587ec-ff65-4b61-b0e8-2a00513494ee",
    "ParentWebUrl": "/sites/Team_49de5296",
    "Title": "Школьные материалы 2."
  }
}
```

Though when I go to the SharePoint portal the URL for the library is https://somesite.sharepoint.com/sites/Team_49de5296/2/Forms/AllItems.aspx. Platform that I use supports only listUrls and for my library it is "/sites/Team_49de5296/2". How can I get it from the Create Document Library Response? Should I do separate query to get it? What property would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its not available in the Created list response.

But you can get it from a deferred property called `RootFolder` which will have a URL to make that request . It is not available by default for performance reasons.

So, you can modify from below sample code:

```
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists";

$.ajax({
    url: fullUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' },
        'BaseTemplate': 100,
        'Title': "Test JS List"
    }),
    headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);

        // get the RootFolder endpoint 
        var listRootFolderEndpoint = data.d.RootFolder["__deferred"]["uri"];        

        $.getJSON(listRootFolderEndpoint, function( rootFolderListData ) {
            // Make a GET request and then get data 
            console.log(rootFolderListData);
            var listServerRelativeUrl = rootFolderListData.ServerRelativeUrl);
        }); 

    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});?
```

Comment: By the way, is there any specific reason to use "odata=verbose" and set request digest header?

Comment: Found answer for odata=verbose (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/). Seems like I just need to choose if I should set it or not depending on the response fields that I require.